# Why do I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'"?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two tables `person` and `customer`. When deleting from `person` I want to delete from `customer`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELCUS
ON Person
AFTER DELETE
FOR EACH ROW
begin
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE customer.PersonID_Fk=Person.PersonId;
end
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DELCUS, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
```

Why can't it read for each row?

Comment: There is no `FOR EACH ROW` in SQL Server - the trigger will be called **once per statement** (and **NOT** once per row) and might be called with **multiple rows** in its `Inserted` and/or `Deleted` pseudo tables which hold the rows being inserted, updated or deleted. Your trigger needs to be able to handle multiple rows at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, you want this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELCUS
ON Person
AFTER DELETE AS
begin
DELETE c 
FROM customer
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from deleted where customer.PersonID_Fk=deleted.PersonId);
end
```

If you're using MySQL, it's this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELCUS
ON Person
AFTER DELETE AS
begin
DELETE c 
FROM customer
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from old where customer.PersonID_Fk=old.PersonId);
end
```

But really, if you actually have an FK set up, it'll error out when you try to delete a person for referential failures, anyway. Your best bet is to set your FK up as `on delete cascade`.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DELCUS, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'begin'.

Comment: @nikparsa - forgot the `as` :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use:

```
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE customer.PersonID_Fk in (select personid from deleted)
```